# Exclude .spec files minified by grunt-contrib-jshint

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-jshint

I'm using the yeoman angular generator. In this generator the test are placed in a seperate folder `'test'`. I rather keep them in the same folder as my .js files. I give them the name `.spec.js`. I need to fix this in my `Gruntfile.js` file so they are not included in minification, jshint etc.

Is there anyway I can exclude files ending with .spec.js?

```
// Make sure there are no obvious mistakes
jshint: {
  options: {
    jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
    reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
  },
  all: {
    src: [
      'Gruntfile.js',
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
    ]
  },
  test: {
    options: {
      jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
    },
    src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `!` in front of an expression to ignore it :

**E.g** : `!**/*.spec.js`

**In your case** :

```js
all: {
    src: [
      '!**/*.spec.js',
      'Gruntfile.js',
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
    ]
  },
  test: {
    options: {
      jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
    },
    src: ['!**/*.spec.js','test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
  }
```